# Can't connect MySQL / Eclipse / iText last error: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to connect to my database using Eclipse just to try to generate some values into a PDF. I'm using the external library iText which is imported on the "Referenced Libraries" folder on the project. The code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.*;

public class GeneratePDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String file_name = "E:\\Programas\\mypdf.pdf";
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file_name));
            document.open();

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "a1s2d3f4g5");
            System.out.println("Connection called");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from codes");

            while (rs.next()) {
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(rs.getString("sl_no") + " " + rs.getString("name"));
                document.add(para);
                document.add(new Paragraph(" "));
            }
            con.close();
            document.close();
        } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException | SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

For me it was a pretty simple code for a first timer connecting to MySQL. Then the errors appeared.
First:

```
 "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

I imported the "mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar" into the project and it replied `Loading class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'.`
So I switched the code to:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); // "Solved"
```

Second:

```
WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended.
```

Then I added "?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", the code went to:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "a1s2d3f4g5"); // "Solved"
```

Third:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

I thought it would be really simple to connect to MySQL but now I have no idea why it isn't connecting. I don't know if this might be a problem but I have two hard disks, Workbench and Connector are on C: and Eclipse as well as the projects are on E:. I tried importing the .jar connector to a folder on the project but no significant changes.

Comment: are you sure that MySQL server is running ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, otherwise it would be 'Disconnected' on workbench i guess